# ClearCase - How lock a file only on a specific branch

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

Can someone to point me to lock a file only on a specific branch in clearcase? Note that i want the same file to be modified in all other branches that other teams working on...

Locking the branches as appropriate might help.But it does not sound like a good idea. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock a specific branch instance.

> cleartool lock co.exe@@/main/foo

Locks that branch instance and will block anyone from modifying that branch while allowing all other instances -- like ci.exe@@/main/foo/2 to be checked out and used.

Depending on your view setup, you may have to use lsvtree or cleartool find to find all the branch instances.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be a simple [`clearool lock`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-2-1-4&lang=en), as it would lock the element for all branches.

A simple approach would be a `cleartool checkout -reserved`, but that owuld prevent checking on other branches as well.

That leaves you with a preop checkout trigger, using the [trigger environment variables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120991) `CLEARCASE_BRTYPE` :

```
cleartool mktrtype -c "Prevent checkout on a branch" -element -all -preop checkout -execwin "ccperl \\shared\path\to\triggers\lock_on_branch.bat" LOCK_ON_BRANCH
```

The script will use:

```
 CLEARCASE_XPN
```

> (All operations; element triggers only) Same as `CLEARCASE_ID_STR`, but prepended with `CLEARCASE_PN` and `CLEARCASE_XN_SFX` values, to form a complete VOB-extended path name of the object involved in the operation.

```
CLEARCASE_BRTYPE
```

> (All operations that can be restricted by branch type) Branch type involved in the operation that caused the trigger to fire. In a rename operation, the old name of the renamed branch type object.